# What size pan should I use if I want to split a recipe in half that calls for a 13x9 inch pan?

Tags: baking, cookware

I have a recipe that calls for 13x9 glass pan, which I have used over and over successfully. This year for holidays I would like to split the recipe so that I get two smaller end products to give as gifts. How do I do this? What size pan should I use?

Answer (score 4):

I have a couple of 8.5" x 6.5" pans (designed for toaster ovens) that I use for exactly this. The height is about the same as a standard 13" x 9" pan. I've split solid dishes like carrot cake or Spanish Bar Bread and looser ones like Spinach Marie or macaroni and cheese successfully. Just remember to check on the dish earlier than usual as the smaller portions will bake quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Nominally you want 1/2 the square inches so it will be the same height.

```
(13 * 9) / 2 = 58.5
```

Anything close should be good enough.

The answer from user61524 is good (55.25).

Comment: A geometric consideration aimed at perfectionists. If we count the perimeter / surface ratio,  the splitting is a bit more complicated.  The perimeter is usually more crusty and the center of a pie tends to have its peculiarity. In simple words one should not leave much from the original pan proportion, especially if the pans are of medium or small size. Forget in case of not baked spoon- like desserts, such as tiramisù